# Density function of given Interval

Tags: probability, density-function

The Density function of a random variable x is given by

```
f(x) = x^2 + 3x + 2 on the interval [1, 4].
```

The functions is zero if `x > 4` or `x < 1`

What is the average value of a sample of a million random numbers generated from this function?

Comment: You should calculate the Expected Value (or Mean) $\mathbb{E}(X)$ by the formula
$$ \mathbb{E}(X) = \int_1^4 x f(x) dx.$$

Comment: what next I get `144.75` which is not satisfy my answer.

Comment: The [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E3%2B3x²%2B2x+from+1+to+4) should be 141.75

Comment: the real answer should be lies between interval, but this value does not lie in-between interval, in question, there are five options only, options are `2.5, 3.5, 1.5, 3.8, 3.0`,
I try a lot but don't get any of these options.

Comment: Oh! I see... Your density function is not a density function. You should divide it by the total mass $M=\int_1^4 f(x) dx$, so thet you get a real density function $g(x)=f(x)/M$ and $\int_1^4 g(x)dx = 1$.

Comment: It's not possible to answer this question as the average value of a random samples containing 1 million observations will never be the same.

Comment: And the $f$ given is not a density as it doesn't integrate to one.

Comment: If we normalize the function so it integrates to one then the expected value is $63/22\approx 2.86$.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson can you tell me how to you do normalize this function.

Comment: That was an Interview question.

Comment: and badly stuck on this question, thanks to all of you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple conceptual hurdles I will address. In regards to problems involving density functions I have never seen before, one of the first things I will do is first verify that the function given to me is indeed a density function.

By definition, a density function must be nonnegative and integrate to one so we verify this first. Now, $f$ is clearly nonnegative, i.e. $f\geq 0$, everywhere outside the interval $[1,4]$. Further investigation into the function on $[1,4]$ also reveal $f$ satisfies the nonnegativity criteria. Next, we check to see if $f$ integrates to one. Let $\mathbf 1_{A}$ denote the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) which, by definition, is one when $A$ is true and zero otherwise. Then, integrating our function $f$ we have
$$
M
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty (x^2 + 3x + 2) \mathbf 1_{x\in[1,4]}\,\mathrm dx
=\int_1^4 (x^2 + 3x + 2)\,\mathrm dx
=\frac{99}{2}.
$$
So we see that $f$, as given, is not a density function. As such, we will define the density function by *normalizing* $f$ via
$$
g_X(x)=\frac{f(x)}{M}=\frac{2}{99}(x^2 + 3x + 2) \mathbf 1_{x\in[1,4]}.
$$
Now that we have a density function our next question is:

*What is the average value of a sample of a million random numbers generated from this function?*

Using [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) I generated one-million observations from $g_X$ and took the mean to get: $\bar x=2.8629$. Generating another million and taking the mean gives: $\bar x=2.86388$. Indeed, if we keep repeating this procedure we will get a different answer every time which is due to the fact that the data generating the averages is random (or at least pseudo-random)! As such, our question cannot be answered.

Now, we can assign an [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) to our density $g_X$ which can loosely be thought of as the "average value" obtained from an infinite number of samples. Using the definition of expected value, if $X\sim g_X$, then
$$
\mathsf E X=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xg_X(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_1^4 x\frac{2}{99}(x^2 + 3x + 2)\,\mathrm dx=63/22=2.86364.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.